# Allocation of shipments based on ranking (excel based solution)

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have got some list of shops. I have to allocate shipments based on their rankings. The allocation should happen in such a way that each shop should not get less than 25 shipments and more than 100 shipments. The actual question is explained below.

```
Total SHipments=150

Shop Id              A         B          C          D            E

Allocation (%)       30%      28%        25%         10%          7%

Min.                 25       25         25          25           25

Max.                100       100        100         100          100

Actual Allocation  %*150
                   =45        42         37           15          11

My Requirement     45(>25)   42(>25)    37(>25)      25(<25)      1(<25)
```

So my requirement is based on the ranking, the excel should allocate actual allocation to the top rankers (Between 25 to 100) and as the ranking goes down, it should fulfil the need of better ranker and make it 25 and then allocate the rest.I think I have made the question clear but let me know if still ambiguity is there. I'm new to this community. Forgive me if I'm not able to post the question in proper way.

Comment: You can set this up and use the Solver. Then change values and re-solve...

Comment: please advise the expected allocation using your example if the shipments are `80` and `360`

Comment: Actually allocation C is 37.5 and for E is 10.5 .  In your table above you show 37 and 11.  Do you want decimal rounded, rounded up or rounded down.  What is currently shown seems inconsistent with excel.  Can you clarify please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get your required results based on the information in your table layed out in the manner in the screen shot below, use the following formula:

```
=INT(MIN(MAX($C$1*B$5,B$7),B$9))
```

The above formula is placed in Cell B16.  The INT was used as your results for 37.5 was 37.

In cell C16 place the following formula and copy it to the right as required.  This is based on the allocation being in descending order from left to right:

```
=IF(SUM($B$16:B$16)+INT(MIN(MAX($C$1*C$5,C$7),C$9))<=$C$1,INT(MIN(MAX($C$1*C$5,C$7),C$9)),$C$1-SUM($B$16:B$16))
```

The max function is used to return the minimum value.  When your formula returns a result below the minimum value The max function returns the minimum value.  The MIN function does the same when the result of the formula exceeds the maximum allowable value.  It will return the maximum allowed value as it is the minimum of the two numbers.

[image: POC]

## UPDATE:  Rank out of order

This does not work when their is a tie and total demand exceeds available shipments

I took your table and added a helper row to determine RANK Row 6.  I used the following formula to come up with the rank

```
=RANK(B5,$B$5:$F$5)
```

With this method, it is possible to have ties.  You can investigate how to come up with unique rank with ties.  The rest of this solution will assume the there are no ties in rank.

In Row 11  the "demand" of each shop is calculated based on Max and Min constraints and is rounded down to the nearest integer.  The following formula is placed in B11 and copied right:

```
=ROUNDDOWN((MAX(MIN(B5*$C$1,B9),B7)),0)
```

In row 13 the actually amount to ship or "supply" is determined with the following formula in B13 and copied to the right.

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(($B$6:$F$6<=B6)*$B$11:$F$11)<=$C$1,B11,MAX($C$1-SUMPRODUCT(($B$6:$F$6<=(B6-1))*$B$11:$F$11),0))
```

[image: UPDATE POC]

FYI - SUMPRODUCT performs array like calculations within it.  As a result, avoid using full column/row references such as A:A and instead reduce the range to your data or something closer to it to avoid a lot of excess calculation which may bog down your system.  This is particularly true when the formula is repeated in multiple cells.

Comment: Thank you for providing the solution. It is working. Thanks

Comment: I wanted to know the solution for one more case when the shop ids are not placed in ascending/descending order based on allocation ranking. Assume Shop Id be B (28%), D(10%), E(7%), C(25%), A(30%). My requirement is B(42), D(25), E(1), C(37), A(45). Assuming that the allocation ranking of the shops can't be re-arranged. All the parameters are same. Total shipment-150, Max-100, Min-25. Can I get solution based on ranking without rearranging them in ascending or descending order.

Comment: It may be possible...what happens in the event of ties?  IE all shops have the same rank but the sum of their demand exceed supply?  How do you determine which of the shops get supplied and which gets shorted on its supply?

Comment: I can allocate unique rank with the help of ranking function if two shops have same allocation %. Let's assume Demand>Supply. The total shipment is anything >125 (if 5 shop ids), assume 150/200. Five Shop ids, arranged randomly as per ranking (previous comment arrangement). I want the maximum allocation(%*total shipment) to top ranker, then 2nd top, then 3rd, 4th with left out (if>25, %*total shipment, otherwise minimum 25,can take shipment from 5th too)   and last with either (0, if <25 or %*total if >25)

Comment: It's working fine for now. This solves my problem. Here is the formula for finding unique ranking =RANK(B5,$B$5:$F$5,0)+COUNTIF($B$5:F5,B5)-1   Paste it in B6 of your worksheet. Great help.

Comment: be aware that the above method will bias store ids on the left receiving to receive their full demand than stores on the right as they will always be ranked with a lower integer

Comment: In the case of `360` shipments your solution will allocate `351` to the stores being `100,100,90,36,25`. @RockyKumar did not specify what will happen to the extra `6` units. Should it be allocated to **Store C** given that it has the highest rank among the remaining 3 stores, or should it be allocated proportionally across the remaining stores? Also in the case of `80` shipments, your solution will allocate `0` to **Store E** but in reality shouldn't there be a minimum replenishment per store? Again this needs to be verified by the OP I think. Other than that it is a good solution :)

Comment: As per upper constraint, I'm not supposed to allocate more than 100 shipments to any of the shops. I know as the demand goes higher, the upper limit will touch the maxima. But this is the required construct. I'll leave 6 extra and ask the resource allocator (Hub incharge) to allocate it manually, based on his interest. As the demand goes down, the construct should be maximum allocation to best performer and rest will get if anything is left out. Those who are getting minimum shipments at low demand, they will be our previlaged shops and rewarded in terms of minimum shipments.